# Quote from bbcode

Tags: php, bbcode

I'm currently trying to make a quote system for my forum and since I am using bb-codes throughout the whole system I want to implement this for quoting aswell.

I have created what I want the quote tag to look like: `[quote=83]`
Where the number "83" is the ID of text from my db.

The logic I have been trying to go for is running this code:
`if (strpos($htmltext, '[quote') !== false) {` and then I want to replace it with a function I've created that outputs a quote box with styling. But how can I fetch the number that is within the quote and then something like run this: `$htmltext = str_replace("[quote=83]", quote($row['ID'], $pdo), $htmltext);`

Comment: bbcode already has `[quote]{text}[/quote]`, why don't you use that?

Comment: I want to fetch more data from the specific ID, such as the user and at what time he wrote the selected text

Comment: Then [preg_​replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) might help you

Comment: Had the ability to fetch the int from string with `(int) filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)` and save it as a variable to use for later :)